# How to see who viewed my Facebook profile which is not in my friend list?

Tags: facebook, friends

I have someone not added in my friends list that randomly visits my profile page. How can I know who visited my Facebook profile page besides the persons i’m already friends with?

I know that *right click* → *Source code* → searching for "list" shows the viewers’ IDs, but that is only showing who is already in my friends list.

I need to see who visited my profile and is not in my friends list. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook [does not](https://www.facebook.com/help/205685226136386) [make available](https://www.facebook.com/help/210896588933875) any list of friends or non-friends that have viewed your profile/timeline.  The list you are referencing is the list of friends in the chat sidebar that appears on the right side of the window (if it is wide enough).  Facebook [claims](http://www.facebook.com/help/199139933467308) that this shows the the friends that you've interacted with frequently or recently on Facebook, although it is thought to also include some randomness for serendipity.